# git revert is not reverting anything

Tags: git, gitlab

I am running the command

`git revert bf0db5abaca25748a85aaf3cffc4154b3a6e045a`

, which is an earlier commit with significant changes, but it does absolutely nothing. The output is

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
```

And then it lists a bunch of files, which indeed should not be tracked.
The files that are tracked, however, are not reverted.

I am nervous to use git reset as I have already pushed some changes that I want to get rid of. What am I doing wrong with revert?
If it is relevant, I have reverted to the same commit before, and it worked fine then.

Thank you.

Comment: If reversal went fine you should have gotten a message about a new revision and it should be in your branch. Can you put in your question the output of revert when you run it?

Comment: The output of the revert command is just what it says up there, ie, "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:"

Comment: It doesn't even open up a window for me to type a commit message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what happens when reverting a commit would do nothing. I can reproduce it by doing a revert and then trying to "revert" the commit we just reverted:

```
$ git log --oneline
e5ce573 (HEAD -> master) Revert "two"
876711f two
0849cb0 one
$ git revert 876711f
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Nothing happens, because `two` is what we *did* just revert; reverting it again results in no change.

So I'm guessing that you're in a similar situation. Try doing a `diff` between the commit *before* the one you are reverting and where you are now; if it comes up empty, that's the reason.

Comment: It doesn't come up empty; there are significant differences between the current state of my files and their state on that last commit.

Comment: Well, I'd need to see actual log, actual diff output, etc. But the point is, yes there are situations where appearing to do nothing is the normal behavior when you say `git revert <SHA>`. Your question seemed to evoke outrage or surprise that `git revert` "does absolutely nothing"; I'm saying, "Oh yes, that can certainly happen."

Comment: Another way to look at this is to diff the commit you want to revert with the commit that precedes it, in that order. That is the patch that git would have to replay onto HEAD in order to do the revert.

Comment: Also I’m thinking about your phrase “I have reverted to the same commit before”. You do not revert _to_ a commit, you revert the commit, that is, you undo it. Well, and here you are saying you’ve already undone this commit! But isn’t that exactly the situation I describe in my answer? Reverting it again does nothing.